# Spring post a string via jquery

Tags: jquery, spring

I have search the stackoverflow and can not find an answer to such a simple question. How to send a string in "post" or "put" type to a Spring web service via jquery.

I have some code like this,

```
$.ajax({url:'/some/url', type :'put', data:'test', contentType:'text/plain'})

@RequestMapping(value = "/some/url", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void changePassword(@RequestBody String str) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

this doesn't work, returns 400. If I remove the contentType part, it shows 415.

Can anyone please show some really working code here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to solve this problem, this is quite strange.

The js code looks like this,

```
$.ajax({url:'/some/url', type :'put', 
        data:JSON.stringify('test'), // this must be stringified
        contentType:'application/json'} // this must be json
)
```